# How to configure Woocommerce Payment Methods programmatically?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, multisite

I'm currently developing a Wordpress Multisite website. I need to have the mainsites payment methods on all subsites (Any user should be able to create their own subsite, thats why I can't do this manually).

On [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435234/get-payment-gateway-related-data-in-woocommerce) they show how to get the payment gateways, but I wasn't able to find any information on how to modify those variables programatically.
I have also found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138590/programmatically-change-payment-methods-woocommerce) on how to unset any payment method, but again, they don't say how to set a new payment method or **how to modify existing payment methods**.

I've tryed this code with no success:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_gateways', 1);
function filter_gateways($gateways){
    global $woocommerce;
    switch_to_blog( 1 );   
    $wc_gateways      = new WC_Payment_Gateways();
    $mainsite_gateways = $wc_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
    restore_current_blog();

    return $mainsite_gateways;
}
```

Also tried this just to be sure that it didn't work and nothing happened

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_gateways', 1, 100);
function filter_gateways($gateways){
    global $woocommerce;
    switch_to_blog( 1 );   
    $mainsite_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways(); //modified this
    restore_current_blog();

    return $mainsite_gateways;
}
```

I have a similar issue with emails. I need the mainsite email address to handle all woocommerce emails using the mainsite email templates...

Comment: You could have a look at the browser native intersection observer API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API